# Kinesis firehose writes to S3 but access denied

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis, access-denied, amazon-kinesis-firehose

- I set up a Kinesis Firehose.
- Using a PUT data stream.
- It writes CSV data to S3.
- This is writing cross-account, from one AWS account to
  another one.

This all works fine.
I can download the data it writes to S3, I can query it.

- Another team created a different Firehose
- This was in their AWS account, to write data to my S3 bucket.
- The data arrives, I can see it in the console.
- They are writing in Parquet format.

**For some reason, I get "Access denied" if I try to download or query anything they have written to S3.**

I sent data to the S3 bucket from my own firehose (in a third, different, account), and I can see that fine.
It's only the Parquet-format data from their Firehose that gets **access denied**.

**Troubleshooting**

I compared the object-level permissions between the object from my firehose versus the object from their firehose:
(Each of these come from different accounts into my account where the S3 bucket is).

1. Here are the object permissions on the (CSV, text) object I firehosed into the S3 bucket:

*These are the S3 objects I can read fine.*

**Grantee**: Object owner (external account) Canonical ID: 4aXXXXXXedc8fd
**Object**: Read
**Object ACL**: Read, Write

**Grantee**: Your AWS account Canonical ID: c43XXXXXXXX97958
**Object**: Read
**Object ACL**: Read, Write

2. Here are the Object permissions for the (Parquet JSON) object the other team firehosed into the bucket:

*These are the objects I get **access denied** for.*

These have exactly the same permissions, obviously the object owner account id is different because it is written from a firehose in a different account.

**Grantee**: Object owner (external account) Canonical ID: 2efXXXXXXd5e2d
**Object**: Read
**Object ACL**: Read, Write

**Grantee**: Your AWS account Canonical ID: c43XXXXXXXX97958
**Object**: Read
**Object ACL**: Read, Write

**The problem:**

Why am I getting "Access denied" on the S3 objects the other team's Firehose created?

The object-level permissions look the same.

Answer (score 1):

We applied two fixes, and it worked

1. The role in the target account that the Firehose uses, needs to have S3:PutObjectAcl granted. This was checked early on but after re-checking it had gone, so this was added back.
2. We turned off KMS encryption in the sending account. This was using a key which the target account could not access. This could be fixed by adding permissions to the role that writes the data, but for debugging we stripped everything back to get it to work as a baseline.